# Output changes when I try to fix it my string cutting off

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue where I'm pulling the subject from my outlook using ComObject.
My code:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$PastWeek = (get-date).AddDays(-6)

$Servers = @(
"Server1",
"Server2",
"Server3"
)

#Servers
$RecentItems = $inbox.Folders.Item(3).items | Where-Object { $_.ReceivedTime -gt $PastWeek }
Foreach ($Server in $Servers){
$ReportsEmails = $RecentItems | Where-Object { ($_.Subject -match "$Server") } | Sort ReceivedTime | Select -Last 1
$ReportsEmails |Select ReceivedTime,Subject
}
```

It displays correctly as a list of servers with ReceivedTime and Subject, but it cuts the subject off. When I try to get it to display the whole subject using something like |ft -autosize, wrap, or doing a .width 3000 it separates the list out so each line has it's own ReceivedTime and Subject column headers.

Any ideas how to fix it so it displays the whole subject while also giving me a single list and not separating them would be much appreciated.

I've also tried to remove the part of the subject I don't want with -replace and different .TrimStart() iterations but since what I want to remove has special characters it has failed. I tried to remove: (Server: "Servername")

Comment: "it separates the list out so each line has it's own ReceivedTime and Subject column headers." - this usually indicates that something _else_ it being output in between. Can you show us the _whole_ script (or at least the full `foreach` loop body)?

Comment: That is the whole body, it's those 4 lines. The only thing I omitted is the $PastWeek variable which is just a (get-date).AddDays(-6) the list of servers which just an array like $Servers = @("server1","Server2","Server3"). $RecentItems reads in the inbox contents, I do a match with the servername, and output the results with a Foreach loop.

Comment: What you've posted isn't syntactically valid - at least two `}`'s are missing. Please [update the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70535491/edit) with the correct code :)

Comment: @Squirreljester - as MathiasR.Jessen pointed out, your code is NOT valid. you have two more `{` than you have `}`. **_please fix your posted code so that folks can work with what you actually are working with._**

Comment: All I was missing previously was the last } but I went ahead and copy/pasted my entire script. All I changed was the servernames, and I removed the duplicate code that searches my other outlook folders.